# How do I re-arrange (auto-generated) data into another arrangement in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have code that automatically generates data in the format listed below and I was wondering if Excel had the capability of reformatting it into a more useful format.

For example:

Is it possible to reformat data in this format:

```
website1    6/19/2013   638
website1    6/20/2013   342
website1    6/21/2013   123
website2    6/19/2013   434
website2    6/20/2013   442
website2    6/21/2013   543
```

into this automatically?

```
         6/19/2013    6/20/2013    6/21/2013
website1   638           342          123
website2   434           442          543
```

Comment: Look for [pivot tables](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/datamanagementinexcel/ss/8912pivot_table.htm).

Comment: What language are you using to get the first output? Maybe it is better to add couple of more lines of codes to get it done everything outside Excel :)

Comment: you can do it in VBA looping ..

Comment: @pnuts: I don't have Excel at hand, so I can't write anything that would qualify as an answer. Would you?

Comment: @pnuts: I don't mind if you answer. You can make it "community wiki" if you insist.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of an answer as such:

With labels for your columns select your data array, Insert > Tables - PivotTable, PivotTable, choose whether into the same (as in example) or another (conventional) sheet and drag the fields into the boxes as shown in the Field List in the image:

[image: SO17284487 example]

If the totals are disconcerting their display can be suppressed.